# How do I stop folders automatically opening on my MacBook Pro 2014?

Tags: finder, macos, folders

When I try to move a file into a folder, let's say Folder A, from another folder, let's say Desktop, how can I stop Folder A automatically opening.   I only want to move the file into it, not see the contents.

**Is there a way to stop this?**

I am running macOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Answer (score 9):

The feature you're referring to is called Spring Loaded Folders. Folders should only spring open if you hover (or pause) over a folder for a second or so (depending on your settings).

In other words, if you drag and drop files from your Desktop into Folder A you would let go of the mouse button as soon as your pointer is over Folder A, rather than pausing over it for too long.

You can adjust your settings as follows:

1. Go to System Preferences > Accessibility
2. In the left-hand sidebar, find and select the *Mouse & Trackpad* option.
3. Now use the slider to adjust the Spring-loaded delay time.

**NOTE:** If you wish to disable the Spring-loaded folder feature, you can remove the checkmark next to the slider.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the spring-loaded folders didn't work for me. I had to unselect the haptic folder option:
System Preferences>Trackpad>Point & Click>Force Click and haptic feedback [unselect]
[image: Force Click and haptic feedback option unselected in Trackpad settings]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWpxd.jpg)

Comment: The asker states that they are using a "MacBook Pro 2014"—a device that does not have a Force Touch trackpad.